# Getting this restriction during provide comments?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, new-users

I am getting the below restriction when i am commenting a question.

It show me the message for chat option. But if the user having less reputation he is unable to do the chat.Is there any alternative way to provide solution?

```
Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat and comments are supplements only. If OP has little reputation, he should learn how to write clear questions / answers, ones that does not require clarifications etc.

Tell OP to edit his post with new data, instead of commenting. Then delete your own now-obsolete comments. If needed, repeat. That way you can keep comment count really low, even if making his question a good one will require a lot of iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We will try follow iterative process for a good question or answer with out adding a lots of comment.